# Codility gave strange result of analyze of algorithm

Tags: c#, .net

I've tried to solve the task 'OddOccurrencesInArray' by c# where it needs  to find out unpaired integer in the given array.
The task is prepared on 'app.codility.com' in lessons by the way: "a non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given. The array contains an odd number of elements, and each element of the array can be paired with another element that has the same value, except for one element that is left unpaired."
My solution:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int result=0;
    Array.Sort(A);
    for(int i=0;i<A.Length-1;i+=2){
        if(A[i]!=A[i+1]){
            result=A[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But analyse is built in 'app.codility.com' says I've done by the wrong way:

```
Correctness tests
```

▶
simple1
simple test n=5
✘
WRONG ANSWER
got 0 expected 4
▶
simple2
simple test n=11
✘
WRONG ANSWER
got 0 expected 4
▶
extreme_single_item
[42]
✘
WRONG ANSWER
got 0 expected 42
▶
small1
small random test n=201
✔
OK
▶
small2
small random test n=601
✘
WRONG ANSWER
got 0 expected 4242

Could someone helps me in this case?

**Update.**
Correct form my solution is:

```
public int solution(int[] A)
    {
        int result = 0;

        Array.Sort(A);

        if (A[A.Length - 2] != A[A.Length - 1])
        {
            return A[A.Length - 1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length - 2; i += 2)
        {
            if (A[i] != A[i + 1])
            {
                return A[i];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128605/find-the-odd-occurrences-in-an-array

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if, after sorting, the unpaired integer is the last element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    int result=0;

    foreach(var a in A){
        result = result ^ a;
    }

    return result;
}
```

As each pair of the same number will give 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
// you can also use other imports, for example:
// using System.Collections.Generic;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// Console.WriteLine("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
        var res = A.ToList()
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .Select(x => new {Key= x.Key, Value = x.Count()})
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value%2)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return res.Key;
    }
}
```